# ImageMagick OSX Snow Leopard bad CPU type

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, imagemagick

Installing imagemagick works.

But when I try to run a command it says **bad cpu type.**

What is this and how do I get rid of it so that it works right?

*N.b. I'm 'behind the times' and only using a core solo (if that helps)*

Comment: Which version of ImageMagick did you download? Was it a binary install package or did you build it yourself? If it was a binary install package, what architecture/platform was it built for? What does the `file` command say about the executable you're trying to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may have a 64-bit build of imagemagick which you're trying to run on a 32-bit only CPU.  As Greg noted, running the file command on it will confirm this; it will show you something like this:

```
styrone$ file /usr/local/bin/imagemagick
/usr/local/bin/imagemagick: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/local/bin/imagemagick (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/local/bin/imagemagick (for architecture i386): Mach-O executable i386
```

If you don't see a line with "(for architecture i386)", that's your problem.  You'll need to get a build that supports 32-bit Intel.

Comment: I don't know, maybe I installed it wrong, I can't get the file command to work and show me that...